# How to create private relay, so we are save against DDOS attack if our public relays goes down

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I'm planning to build private relay, in case if my public relay will go down due an attack.

Based on my understanding I do not need register that relay when I register pool using command `cardano-cli stake-pool registration-certificate`

Additionally seems I do need to run `topologyUpdater.sh` to let other know that they can connect to my pool. Without this I assume there will be no incoming connections and no blocks can be pulled from private relay right. Is it correct?

Do I need to run `relay-topology_pull.sh` to pull list of relays?

So it means my private relay should be build completely in same way as normal relay, I just do not register it with command `cardano-cli stake-pool registration-certificate`.

Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to run relay-topology_pull.sh to pull list of relays?

Yes.

> So it means my private relay should be build completely in same way as normal relay, I just do not register it with command cardano-cli stake-pool registration-certificate.
>
> Correct?

Yes, that's right. You want your relay to work just like your other relays. The only difference is that this relay is not identifiable as yours.